# After installing Ubuntu, Windows still thinks it has the full disk for itself

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a brand new laptop shipped with Windows 10 on a 128GB SSD. In the Ubuntu installer, I resized the Windows partition to 40GB, and allocated to the rest to Ubuntu.

Now, when I boot on Windows, it still says that it has ~120GB on C:. So I'm afraid that eventually Windows will overwrite the Linux partition :-(

Am I safe? If not, how can I convince Windows that it only has 40GB? And do I need to reinstall Ubuntu to do so?

Here is the output of `lsblk`:

`NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/86
loop1    7:1    0  86,6M  1 loop /snap/core/4486
loop2    7:2    0   3,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop3    7:3    0 139,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
loop4    7:4    0  21,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/31
loop5    7:5    0   4,9M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/41
loop6    7:6    0   2,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/167
loop7    7:7    0   1,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop8    7:8    0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop9    7:9    0  86,6M  1 loop /snap/core/4650
loop10   7:10   0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop11   7:11   0 162,1M  1 loop /snap/spotify/13
loop12   7:12   0  12,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop13   7:13   0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/39
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  37,2G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1G  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  80,9G  0 part /`

Comment: Please run `sudo lsblk`, and [edit] your question to add the output from that command.

Comment: It may help to boot into Windows and run `chkdsk /f X:` where X: is the partition with the Windows operating system, often but not always C: This will not really be done until you reboot (and it will run in the boot process before Windows starts).

Comment: I just rebooted in order to follow @sudodus advice, and it happens that now, windows reports the correct size for C:...

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. I can make it an 'answer' to make it easier for other people to find it :-)

Comment: @sudodus sorry I wasn't clear: I didn't even perform the `chkdsk`, the size correct immediately after reboot. So I'm reluctant to mark this as "the" answer -- I don't even know if this would have fixed the problem, had it persisted. However I'll upvote you -- sorry I forgot.

Comment: new laptop, same problem. This time it didn't fall into place on its own, I had to use @sudodus fix, and it worked. My guess is that, in in the previous case, Windows spontaneously checked the disk in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows should 'check the disk'

Boot into Windows and run

```
 chkdsk /f X:
```

where `X:` is the partition with the Windows operating system, often but not always `C:`

This will not really be done until you reboot (and it will run in the boot process before Windows starts).